# How do you allow IIS to access a symlink folder?

Tags: iis, permissions, symlink

I have a two webservers, on each webserver in the C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles I have created a symbolic link to the other servers log file folders, so essentially I can be logged in to one of the webservers and see the logs on both servers in one place. This works perfectly.

I am building a webpage to make the log files available via a webpage, the code simply goes to the C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles directory and lists the files in each sub folder, i.e. W3SVC1 (the local folder) and webserver2-w3svc1 (the remote log folder).

For the local folders it works fine, but I am getting the "access denied" error when trying to call Directory.GetFiles on the symlinkd folder. I suspect this is some sort of permissions error, but I tried giving the symlinkd folder full permissions to "everyone" but I still get the same error.

Is this something to do with the fact that when I created the symlinkd I had to enter the username and password of the webserver2, and these credentials cannot be accessed/used by IIS when trying to get access to the folder?

Is there anything I can do allow IIS to access the contents of this symlinkd folder?

Comment: On IIS your code is executed in session 0 under the application pool identity. Thus, there are far too many differences from running the same code in your user session.  Things like mapped drives and symlink folders are really just there for convenience and you don't need that convenience when they don't work with IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, the only way to do this is as follows:

1. Create a new user on the computer.
2. Run the AppPool in IIS under this new users' identity as opposed to the default IUSR account.
3. Give the folder you are sharing permissions to this user AND 'share' this folder with the new user.

Comment: I had the same problem. Asked my only mate ChatGPT. It suggested to add IIS_IUSRS with full permissions to that specific folder under properties > Security > edit groups. I did it and worked. So just another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use a symlink, you can create a virtual directory mapping to that directory in IIS, just map it to the target path. In IIS, right click on the website and select Add Virtual Directory.

For more information, please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/create-virtual-directory-folder-remote-computer).

Comment: If you don't want the general public to access this folder, only restricted users on your webapp, this is approach does not work. It will work if you want everyone to see the contents of the folder, but for logs, this is not appropriate.